# Getting MSSQL Stored Proc Results with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a reasonably complicated stored procedure in MSSQL 2008 R2 that, in the end, results in a small table being returned. The PHP will be called from javascript and I want it to return the array as JSON to be used in table in the javascript.

I am using PHP to access it and, using the profiler, can see that I am calling the SP and passing the correct parameters to it.

My PHP looks like this:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=(local);Database=cddDispo");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode("Error connecting to the server.");
    die ();
}

$lot = $_POST["lot-input"];
$layerAdder = $_POST["layer-input"];

$adder = substr($layerAdder,-3,3);
$adder = str_replace('=','',$adder);
$layer = substr($layerAdder,0,strpos($layerAdder,' '));

$sth = $dbh->prepare('EXEC dbo.pullDispo ?,?,?');

$sth->bindParam(1,$lot,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(2,$layer,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(3,$adder,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$array = array();

try {
    $sth->execute();

    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //I want to build my output array here
   }
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error getting data, please try again.";
    die();
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

This is the first time that I have tried to return table results from a stored procedure and even with several PHP Manual/ Google searches I have not figured out how to capture the table back in the PHP.  I have a less elegant workaround (write the SP table to a static table and call that table later in the PHP) but would rather figure out if I can do in a more elegant manner.  Any advice is much appreciated.

I thought it might be useful if I posted my final code:

```
function array_push_assoc($array,$key,$value) {
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=(local);Database=cddDispo');
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode('Error connecting to the server.');
    die ();
}

$lot = $_POST['lot'];
$layer = $_POST['layer'];
$adder = $_POST['adder'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare('EXEC dbo.pullDispo ?,?,?');

$sth->bindParam(1,$lot,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(2,$layer,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(3,$adder,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$results = array();
$combinedArray = array();
$array = array();
$count = 0;

try {
    $sth->execute();
    do {
        $results[] = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }while ($sth->nextRowset());

    foreach($results as $row) {
        if($count == 0) {
            $headerArray =
                [
                    'Lot'               =>$row['Lot'],
                    'Layer'             =>$row['Measured Layer'],
                    'Product'           =>$row['MES Product'],
                    'Adder'             =>$row['Adder Chart']
                ];
            $combinedArray = array_push_assoc($combinedArray,'header',$headerArray);
        }

        $count++;

        //This is for formatting of final table
        if($row['UDL'] == 0) {
            $udl = 'NA';
        } else {
            $udl = round($row['UDL'],4);
        }

        $infoArray =
            [
                'Wafer'             =>$row['Wafer'],
                'Type'              =>$row['Type'],
                'Count'             =>$row['Count'],
                'CDD'               =>round($row['CDD'],3),
                'UCL'               =>round($row['UCL'],4)
            ];
        array_push($array,$infoArray);
    }
    $combinedArray = array_push_assoc($combinedArray,'detail',$array);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode('Error running stored procedure.');
    die();
}

echo json_encode($combinedArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that your stored procedure is returning multiple result sets? This includes output like warning messages or number of rows affected. Try adding `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` or `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your stored procedures after the `AS`. You can also try advancing to the next result set in PHP before trying to get the results by calling `$stg->nextRowset()` before `$sth->fetchAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fetchAll()` to get your resultset, then encode that array as your json response:

```
$array = array();
try {
    if($sth->execute()){
        $array = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $array = array('error'=>'failed to execute()')
    }
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error getting data, please try again.";
    die();
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This still did not help.  I think the issue may be that I can't return a full table of results from SQL, only integer values indicating (e.g., success, failure)

Comment: At the end of the stored procedure it's the equivalent of running a  SELECT * FROM [table] where the output would has 16 columns of data and is generally less than 50 entries long.  What I have went with is to put that data into a static table, then call that table next in the stored procedure through the SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a stored procedure with multiple result sets, you probably do not want to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` into every procedure you have; you always can add

```
$dbh->setAttribute(constant('PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY'), true);
$dbh->query("SET NOCOUNT ON");
```

before of

```
$dbh->prepare($query);
```

and it will work.